# Trying to add a RelativeLayout programmatically but seems like it's off screen or too big

Tags: android, android-layout, android-relativelayout

I have this xml for a screen where I at the top I will have a spinner with a list of search conditions, a button next to it (this is what I call control area) and each time is pressed, a group of views will be added for an extra search. The group comprises of another spinner where the user will specify the operator (AND, OR), a text box with the title of the search condition and an edit text where the user will put the input (this is what I call filter area). This will be used to build a search query for a database search later on.

The xml below is what I have so far with a group hardcoded so I can show what I add programatically.

```
<ScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true"> <!--IMPORTANT otherwise backgrnd img. will not fill the whole screen -->

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/searchLayout"
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        tools:context="com.kadis.materialref.Search">

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/attributeSelector"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/controlElementHeight"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/addAttributeButton"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/controlElementHeight"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/controlElementHeight"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/attributeSelector"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/attributeSelector"
            android:onClick="addSearchCondition"
            android:text="@string/addSearchAttributeString"/>

        <View
            android:id="@+id/dividerControl1"
            style="@style/Divider"
            android:layout_below="@+id/attributeSelector"/>

        <View
            android:id="@+id/dividerControl2"
            style="@style/Divider"
            android:layout_below="@+id/dividerControl1"/>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/FilterArea0"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/controlElementHeight"
            android:layout_below="@+id/dividerControl2"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true">

                <Spinner
                    android:id="@+id/filterOperator0"
                    android:layout_width="@dimen/controlElementHeight"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"/>

                <TextView
                    style="@style/SearchFormTitle"
                    android:id="@+id/filterTitle0"
                    android:text="@string/column1"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/filterOperator0"
                    android:layout_toEndOf="@id/filterOperator0"
                    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"/>

                <EditText
                    style="@style/SearchFormFieldText"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/filterTitle0"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/filterOperator0"
                    android:layout_toEndOf="@id/filterOperator0"
                    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"/>

        </RelativeLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

The screen is something like this
[image]

The function called when the button is pressed to add another filter area is the following. The function generateViewId is the same as after API 17, I just added it in the class for API < 17.

```
public void addSearchCondition(View view)
{
    // Get selection from spinner in control area; the attribute to add in the search conditions.
    Spinner attributeSelector = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.attributeSelector);
    String attributeSelected = attributeSelector.getSelectedItem().toString();

    // Get layout where I will add stuff.
    RelativeLayout searchLayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.searchLayout);

    // Get last id of the last child so we know under which to add the new layout
    int bottomChildId = searchLayout.getChildAt(searchLayout.getChildCount()-1).getId();

    //
    // New Relative Layout to be added.
    //
    RelativeLayout filterLayout = new RelativeLayout(this);
    filterLayout.setId(generateViewId());
    // Define width and height parameters.
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams rlp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            R.dimen.controlElementHeight);
    // Define position
    rlp.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, bottomChildId);
    rlp.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_START);
    rlp.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_LEFT);
    filterLayout.setLayoutParams(rlp);

    //
    // Add the operator spinner.
    //
    Spinner operatorSpinner = new Spinner(this);
    operatorSpinner.setId(Search.generateViewId());
    // Get the options for the spinner.
    String[] operators = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.operators);
    // Add items on the spinner.
    ArrayAdapter<String> spinnerArrayAdapter =
            new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, operators);
    spinnerArrayAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    operatorSpinner.setAdapter(spinnerArrayAdapter);
    // Define width and height parameters.
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams rlpSp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
            R.dimen.controlElementHeight,
            R.dimen.controlElementHeight);
    // Define position
    rlpSp.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_LEFT);
    rlpSp.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_START);
    // Set layout parameters
    operatorSpinner.setLayoutParams(rlpSp);
    // Add spinner on the layout
    filterLayout.addView(operatorSpinner);

    //
    // Add a text view as the title
    //
    final TextView tv = (TextView)getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.search_attribute_title, null);
    tv.setId(Search.generateViewId());
    // Set text to display
    tv.setText(attributeSelected);
    // Define width and height parameters.
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams rlpTV = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    // Define position
    rlpTV.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT);
    rlpTV.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_END);
    rlpTV.addRule(RelativeLayout.RIGHT_OF, operatorSpinner.getId());
    rlpTV.addRule(RelativeLayout.END_OF, operatorSpinner.getId());
    // Set layout parameters
    tv.setLayoutParams(rlpTV);
    // Add spinner on the layout
    filterLayout.addView(tv);

    // Add an Edit Text as the placeholder for the user input
    final EditText et = (EditText)getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.search_attribute_input, null);
    et.setId(Search.generateViewId());
    // Set text to display
    et.setText(attributeSelected);
    // Define width and height parameters.
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams rlpET = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    // Define position
    rlpET.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT);
    rlpET.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_END);
    rlpET.addRule(RelativeLayout.RIGHT_OF, operatorSpinner.getId());
    rlpET.addRule(RelativeLayout.END_OF, operatorSpinner.getId());
    rlpET.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, tv.getId());
    // Set layout parameters
    et.setLayoutParams(rlpET);
    // Add spinner on the layout
    filterLayout.addView(et);

    // Adding the whole filter layout to the search layout (whole screen)
    searchLayout.addView(filterLayout);
}
```

I am not sure if the problem might be the LayoutParameters for textView and editText but to add the rules I have to have the LayoutParameters and I have to pass some arguments. Maybe I should pass the wrap_content since in the xml hardcoded I have I don't pass them?

I have debugged and the Layout is created and added. The ids are generated and when I press on the screen is like the white space below the hardcoded xml reacts like it's the spinner with the operator choices. So I am guessing something goes wrong with the dimensions maybe?
After pressing the button and the filter area is "added" If I press the white area where it was supposed to be the spinner of the are (with the operators) is triggered

[image]

The dimensions I have so far are the following defined just in case

```
    <dimen name="activity_horizontal_margin">16dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="activity_vertical_margin">16dp</dimen>

    <!-- Fonts sizes -->
    <dimen name="titleBig">48sp</dimen>
    <dimen name="titleMed">36sp</dimen>
    <dimen name="titleSmall">24sp</dimen>
    <dimen name="searchTitle">10sp</dimen>
    <dimen name="searchField">15sp</dimen>

    <!-- Padding -->
    <dimen name="titlePadding">20dp</dimen>

    <!-- Element heights -->
    <dimen name="controlElementHeight">40dp</dimen>
```

Also, when I choose another choice in the spinner with the attributes (the search filters) the button disappears, I think gets shoved off screen to the right? How can I fix that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So in the code where you create the `LayoutParams` for the `RelativeLayout`:

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams rlp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
        R.dimen.controlElementHeight);
```

You are not actually passing the dimension as the height, but rather the unique identifier of that dimension resource. You can actually see the value if you open `R.java` for your project and search for `controlElementHeight`. So you are probably passing a huge integer value in as the height as the IDs are values like `0x7f0a0047`.

What you really want is something like this:

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams rlp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                getResources().getDimensionPixelSize( R.dimen.controlElementHeight) );
```

This will request the actual value of the defined dimension resource, scaled to the device's screen density.

Comment: Thank you, I feel really silly now. Very careless of me.

Comment: @AndreasAndreou Nah, no worries. Some methods take IDs, some take explicit values. Happens. :)